# Does IBM MobileFirst platform provide auto-sync feature?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i would like to know if the IBM MobileFirst platform provides auto-sync facility?? I am aware of the Appear IQ framework where as a developer one does not have to code the data sync part, instead it is handled by the platform.

I am reading the docs but so far i have not found anything indicating such a feature exists. Just wanted to confirm the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what are you referring to "auto-sync".

- MobileFirst provides JSONStore with database sync functionality: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_overview.html?lang=en
- There is also the Direct Update feature for Hybrid applications: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-client-side-development/using-direct-update-to-quickly-update-your-application/

Comment: thanks for your response! By auto-sync i am referring to the scenario where the framework handles the synchronization by itself. The developer does not have to code separately. Anyways, i feel that the MobileFirst platform does not support such a feature and instead the developer has to mark records as dirty and then push them to the server. Thanks for the links you shared. They are helpful!